# How do i make a multiple negative regex?

Tags: php, regex

My website must indentfy when url doesn´t contain:

1- the word 'topics'
2- any word beggining with 'adm_'
3- any number

i have tried:

`$route['([^topics_adm_0-9])'] = 'posts/details/$1';
 $route['([^topics|^adm|^0-9])'] = 'posts/details/$1';`

Also, could someone tell me please, if is there a tool that can help me
with regex in the future? All sites i found that do this requires knowledge from user. Thank you all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will not find a regex tool that does not require knowledge from the user.

Comment: If this question id duplicated, let the link for i see the response, i didn´t find anything